# my react-native app fail to send body in POST request to backend url

Tags: react-native

As i am trying to send my data in form of body in backed url as in backed i have made something if it dont receive body it will send `sucess: false, msg: haven't received body` else `sucess: true, msg: jwt token` as if i make request from post man with same data it's working but sending via. native app it fails to send.. any help will be helpfull

As 1st request is from postman and 2nd from my app

[image]

```
const handleLogin = (Enrno, Pass) => {
setError(null);
setIsLoaded(false);
setItems([]);
fetch(config.url + "/login", {
  method: "POST",
  header : {
    Accept  : 'application/json',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
   },
  body : JSON.stringify({
    "enrno": Enrno,
    "password" : Pass
  })
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setItems(result);
      alert(items[0].msg);
    },
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setError(error);
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put these to headers, not header.

```
    Accept  : 'application/json',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
```

So, it should look like this.

```
fetch(config.url + "/login", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    enrno: Enrno,
    password : Pass
  })
})
```